# Overlap item over every other item in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, mobile, stack

I want to overlap an item of my `ListView` over every other item (upper and lower items), like the following image:

[image]

The closest I've got is here, and as you can see, I'm having this overlapping problem:

[image]

I've done [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ba271a23a82b5458a5fff19129c0f394&null_safety=true) to test the screenshot's behavior with my current approach, however, I have ran out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `stack` placing the main focused widget on bottom level?

Comment: I did but it doesn't seem to work, it wont overlap other list elements.

Comment: i would say instead of `an item of ListView`, remove it from list and store them on temp data, then use stack and place the temp data on bottom level stack.

Comment: The problem with that is that I must be able to scroll while that layer is visible, an extra top layer would just make it extra-difficult in this case since I'd need a global `ScrollController`, and move its `Positioned` based on the `scroll.position`.